# Marry a girl whos done zina with 2 person

Tags: nikah

A girl is engaged later she informed. she was in physical relation with 2 of her boy friend in past.what is the best option can a person should marry or leave.

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you marry a God fearing woman who fears Allah and is a good Muslimah. Remember you are finding a woman that will be a mother of your future children. So find someone who has good character and is beautiful.

But if the woman you are marrying has said that she done tawbah, then you should decide for yourself.

I hope you have best in this world and in the akhirah.